# UPDATE con INNER JOIN en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger, transacciones

Tengo este esquema de base de datos para una agenda electrónica.

Tengo una tabla de eventos y una de equipamientos la cual es una relación muchos a muchos. Una vez que se elimina un evento, necesito cambiar el estado de los  equipos (por ej: proyector, notebook, puntero) relacionados a ese evento, los cuales se almacenan en la tabla `evt_equip`.

Mi idea es hacer esto con un Trigger, de manera que una vez que se elimine un evento, se dispare el trigger y se cambie de estado a los equipos relacionados al evento (de 1 a 0).

Pienso que el camino correcto es hacer una UPDATE con JOIN pero ahí esta el problema. Me la pase probando y no consigo el resultado.

[image]

El código que estuve probando es este:

```
delimiter //
create trigger evento_AD after delete on evento for each row
begin
declare id int;
set id=old.idevento;
insert into pruebas(valor) value(id);
update equipamiento e inner join evt_equip ee on e.idequipamiento = ee.idequip set estado=0 where ee.idevento=id;
end//
```

Comment: *y no consigo el resultado*: ¿qué sucede? Sería bueno que compartieras un scrit que sea un [mcve] para que podamos reproducir tu problema.

Comment: @sstan el trigger que estoy usando es el que esta publicado, no hay nada mas para publicar. Se ejecuta después de hacer un DELETE de un evento

Comment: Esta parte la tienes tal cual en tu trigger?: `//esta es una insercion de depuracion para probar si es correcto el id del evento`?  Porque el `//` le pone fin al trigger, por lo que el update queda excluido.

Comment: no no, esa es una linea de comentario para que el lector sepa para que es esa linea de codigo, si se mal entiende la saco

Comment: Sí, es mejor que incluyas el trigger exactamente como lo tienes de verdad. En realidad, lo que se necesita son 2 cosas: 1) que especifíques claramente el problema. Decir que "no consigues el resultado" no es claro. Hubo un error, no hizo nada, hizo un update de un registro incorrecto, ¿qué?  2) Incluye un script completo y preciso que nos permita reproducir tu error. Solo el trigger no es suficiente, porque no tenemos el script de creación de tus tablas. El enlace [mcve] explica muy bien lo que se necesita.

Comment: a perfecto, bueno lo haré así entonces, igualmente si te sirve de algo. ese trigger no hace nada, se genera perfectamente sin error, pero al dispararse no hace nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

evt_equip es una entidad débil que requiere tanto de la tabla evento como de equipamiento para identificarse. Por lo que si intentas borrar un evento que se referencie en evt_equip te debería dar error.

Si tu finalidad es cambiar el estado del equipamiento para que queden libres cuando se finalice un evento, te recomiendo que en lugar de borrar el evento, actualices el equipo que está ocupado por eventos caducados:

```
UPDATE equipamiento 
SET estado = 0 
INNER JOIN evt_equip ON (idequipamiento = idequip) 
INNER JOIN evento ON (evento.idevento = evt_equip.idevento) 
WHERE evento.fecha_fin < sysdate
```

Comment: genial muchas gracias me sirvio tu aporte